# Rails 6 Webpacker Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slick is not a function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm fairly new to Rails 6 and Webpacker. The scenario is, I have added a package through yarn named 'slick-carousel'. And I am using

```
require('slick-carousel')
```

to require the package. And I have a custom js file `'custom-slick.js'` which uses a function from the `slick.js` file in `slick-carousel` package. And I tried permutation and combination of both below -

```
import './slick-custom.js'
```

and

```
require('./slick.js');
```

Nothing seems to work and says `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slick is not a function`.
**My guess and I'm kind of sure that the `'custom-slick.js'` is getting defined before the initialization of `slick.js`.** I also tried to require only the package first and add the below before the end of body tag as well as import the package in the custom file. But doesn't seem to work.

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'slick-custom' %>
```

I have found two ways to make it work.

1. Paste the `slick.js` library in `apps/javascripts/packs`, add the `custom-slick.js` functions to `slick.js` and add below before the body tag in html.erb `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'slick' %>`
2. Require the library as usual. Put the `custom-slick.js` in `app/assets/javascripts`, add it to rails assets pipeline like `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w[slick-custom.js]` and then `<%= javascript_include_tag 'slick-custom' %>`

Both of them works but are kind of messy. Is there any better and rails-webpacker-y way to achieve this?